# Set image height from image URL to PinterestLayout CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, url, uicollectionview

I create a CollectionView with PinterestLayout, so this is a collection view with different cells hight. It's work, but when I put my code to the project with Firestore (when image in cells I take from URL) I have a problem, because in this line "let photo = post.floverImg" I think I have to put something like in cell "cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: flovers[indexPath.row].floverImg!))" to show Image and not String.

extension HomeViewController {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return flovers.count
}

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: flovers[indexPath.row].floverImg!))
        cell.label.text = flovers[indexPath.row].floverName
      //  cell.descriptionLabel.text = flovers[indexPath.row].floverName
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        
    
        
        
       
        return cell
    }
}




func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    
    if let post = posts?[indexPath.item], let photo = post.floverImg {
        let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: photo.size(), insideRect: boundingRect)
       
        return rect.size.height
    }
    
    return 200
}
```

https://ibb.co/J3KdDtG
https://ibb.co/JzXZv3V

Comment: Are the images appearing ? If not could you please share your code where you are trying to set the images ? On the other hand if they are appearing what is your issue with them ?

Comment: yes, the problem is in the size of the images, I need them to be the same as the pictures. I added 2 link: how it looks now, and how it should looks. Thank u

Comment: Check this out, take the time to read it through slowly, it will help for sure: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: Unfortunately  he doesn't use the database, but problem is just this

Comment: Yes, but from the post you can get an idea how to resize your collectionViewCells to by dynamic based on the image size

Comment: But both projects (link with screenshots) are mine,  only difference between them is using a database and converting an image from a link, but in any case, thank u)